# Strange fancyhdr Behavior (Book Class)

Tags: fancyhdr, multicol, paralist

When there is a compact list (using the paralist package), the recto header display the page number in the center of the page. Otherwise, the recto header only displays the page number, which is the desired behavior. Worse, when I try to write a MWE, I can't replicate the behavior. This is only an issue on three or four pages of a 200+ page document.

Here's my effort at a MWE (I had to use a lot of text to get push the compact list onto a recto page):

```
\documentclass[12pt,bindingoffset=0.4in]{bookest}
\geometry{paperwidth=5in, paperheight=8in}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase {\rightmark}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Header Issue}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section{tomato}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{compactenum}
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;
\item The type of employment;
\item The probation period;

\end{compactenum}
\end{multicols}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Here's a picture from the original showing the problem. 
[image]

And another, since multiple graphics aren't permitted:

[image]

And a third:

[image]

Comment: I changed the answer to reproduce the `bookest` setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *not* using `fancyhdr` until you issue `\pagestyle{fancy}`. The problem is in bad interaction of `bookest` with `multicols`, but is cured with `fancyhdr` properly initiated:

```
\documentclass[12pt,bindingoffset=0.4in]{bookest}
\geometry{paperwidth=5in, paperheight=8in}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\nouppercase {\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\begin{document}
```

Just the preamble, the rest is as in your example.

[image]

You can get the right behavior with the default `bookest` setting by doing

```
\documentclass[12pt,bindingoffset=0.4in]{bookest}
\geometry{paperwidth=5in, paperheight=8in}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paralist}

\setevenhead{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\evenheadtext \vskip 5pt \makeheadrule}}
\setoddhead{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\oddheadtext \vskip 5pt \makeheadrule}}

\begin{document}
```

The problem is that `bookest` uses `\vbox`, which takes the current value of `\hsize` for setting the paragraph width; when in the middle of a `multicols` environment, this parameter is not the full text width. With a proper LaTeX construction, with `\parbox`, the problem is cured.

Comment: I did get this error, though: Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (14.49998pt): 
 Make it at least 27.04602pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.  //How to fix?

Comment: @user26732 Just do what you're asked to: can you see the line `\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}`? Use the value you're requested to. However, this seems to be due to a long title: avoid them with such narrow pages.